# Combining Array Elements Arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

newbie here. I am trying to combine array elements into a single integer.

I want to combine data elements 11 through 13 into a single number stored in combinedArray. The desired result would be to have combinedArray[1] = 123.

```
uint8_t data[32];
uint8_t combinedArray[2];
data[11] = {'1'};
data[12] = {'2'};
data[13] = {'3'};
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I believe that need to convert the data type in order to concatenate it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `var` instead of `uint8_t`?

Assign to combinedArray like this:

`combinedArray[1] = data[11] + data[12] + data[13]`

You actually are already using Strings in data[]. '1' is a String, 1 is a Number.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do

```
uint8_t data[32];
uint8_t combinedArray[2];
data[11] = {'1'};
data[12] = {'2'};
data[13] = {'3'};
String result = data[11] + data[12] + data[13];
//then you can convert that to a char array by doing result.toChars();
//or converty the result by doing Integer.parseInt(result);
//you WILL have to use chars instead because they will concatenate correctly
//because uint8_t is not a character its a number so when you concatenate              
//them you add the two ascii values together
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple decimal (in ascii) to decimal (numeric) conversion should be enough:

```
combinedArray[1] = 0;             // value must be defined
for (uint8_t * ptr = data+11; ptr != data+14; ++ptr) {
  combinedArray[1] *= 10;         // move previous value by one digit to the left (ie. 12 => 120)
  combinedArray[1] += *ptr - '0'; // substract ascii value of '0' from character to get value and add it to the result
}
```

If using characters for setting elements in `data` array is mistake, then you have to remove `- '0'` so it'll work with correct values: 
Now you have character '1' in `data[11] = {'1'};` with value 49 (ASCII value of character '1').